# How to add a sub-menu to a Gtk Menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk

I have a Gtk menu in my application to which I want to add a submenu. I.e, when the main menu item is clicked, it should expand another list of menu items (A submenu).

I have tried some methods and they don't work. The documentation is sparse on this too.

**Here is my code:**

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

self.menu = Gtk.Menu()
item = Gtk.MenuItem()
item.set_label("Interfaces")
item.connect("activate", self.app.main_window.cb_show, '')
self.menu.append(item)

#Tried this way but it doesn't work.
# self.sub_menu = Gtk.Menu()
# self.menu.append(self.sub_menu)

item = Gtk.MenuItem()
item.set_label("Configuration")
item.connect("activate", self.app.config_window.cb_show, '')
self.menu.append(item)

self.menu.show_all()
```

How can I do this?

**Update:**

I tried using the [gtk.MenuItem.set_submenu](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkmenuitem.html#method-gtkmenuitem--set-submenu) but it still does not work.

```
    self.menu = Gtk.Menu()

    item = Gtk.MenuItem()
    item.set_label("Units")
    self.menu.append(item)

    self.sub_menu = Gtk.Menu()
    submenu_item = Gtk.MenuItem()
    submenu_item.set_label("item text")
    item.set_submenu(self.sub_menu)
```

Comment: You don't add `submenu_item` to `self.sub_menu`.

Comment: @el.pescado thanks! works now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. Create a `Gtk.Menu` representing submenu
2. Create a `Gtk.MenuItem` in parent menu
3. Attach submenu to menu item with [`gtk.MenuItem.set_submenu`](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkmenuitem.html#method-gtkmenuitem--set-submenu)

Something like:

```
item = Gtk.MenuItem("Submenu")
self.menu.append(item)
self.sub_menu = Gtk.Menu()
item.set_submenu(self.sub_menu)
```

Comment: @SapneshNaik I am using Gtk#, but this basic idea of setting a Menu to SubMenu worked. If it does not work, why have you marked it as the answer. If it worked, you need to remove the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

A Menu can only be attached to a MenuItem and a MenuItem can only be added to a Menu or a Menubar.

The hierarchy you want is:

```
menubar
    menuitem (sort of a menu header; it's got the label, "File" for instance)
       menu (the actual file menu)
         menuitem (such as "New")
           menu (actually a submenu)
              item ("Text" for instance)
```

A Menu object can only be attached using set_submenu().

A MenuItem can only be attached using append().